# Tool to Convert table base design to table less design

Tags: html, cross-browser, dreamweaver

What is the best optimized way to convert table base design to table less design? the layout should be cross browser compatible and SEO Friendly. Is there any tool/editor which converts existing table base design to table less design?
Is there any option in dreamweaver to convert the design in tableless?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Now it seems that you have a 3x3 table, which is best left as is if you're just presenting tabular data in it.

Comment: You should not aim at tableless webdesign since tables do their job quite well for presenting tabular data as they were invented for.
  
Your example html changed from a 3 x 3 row table to a table with the same amout of rows and columns but with colspans in it... that does not make a change in the above statement as long as you present data in it and don't use it to create a layout.

Comment: if maybe any editor can do it automatically but it is garbage. because if you write manually you find that mockup was better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good automated way to do this.

If you have well marked up content in the layout tables, then a web developer can implement a similar design using CSS for presentation and the content can be dropped in to it — but that's the best you can really hope for.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do that?

Tables are to be used to present tabular data. In this case there is no need to use any other markup. This is just fine and respects the HTML specification.

However, you should not use tables to markup your document's layout. In this case you should use a combination of headers, divs, paragraphs, list elements, and so on... Styled with some CSS.

A great book on this subject is "Bulletproof Web Design" by Dan Cederholm: http://simplebits.com/work/

Comment: It depends on your content's semantic meaning. I can play with divs and CSS but it will not be perfect. If you are interersted in good SEO, this is important. Also, speaking about SEO, have a look there, it don't hurts: http://powazek.com/posts/2090

Answer (score 1):

> *Why would you do that?* - Arko
>
> **Answer:** Accessibility.
>
> It is important web developers are aware of this.

Accessibility is the primary motivation for using tables to represent tabular data.  Tables are not for defining position and layout of content.  Screen readers interpret table tags to be tabular data (i.e., a spreadsheet of information).

**More information:**

- A Guide to Disability Rights Laws: http://www.usdoj.gov/crt/ada/cguide.htm
- Section 504 of the Rehabilitation Act
  of 1973: **www.section508.gov/index.cfm?FuseAction=Content&ID=15**
- Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act
  of 1973: **www.section508.gov**
- Section 255 of the Telecommunications
  Act of 1996: **www.fcc.gov/cgb/dro/section255.html**
- The Americans with Disabilities Act
  of 1990: **www.ada.gov/pubs/ada.htm**

Answer (score 1):

If you read what he asked, you should understand he is talking about design/layout and not tabular data.

and the statement 
"Tables are to be used to present tabular data. In this case there is no need to use any other markup."

"present" is an ambiguous word, in this context.  Use Tables to align data relative to context. Like when you have something that could be done in a spreadsheet. You should never use tables to align a layout in a website, such usage defines pre CSS/XHTML. (aka oldskool, in the bad way)

BTW, when people say "tableless design"   they almost always mean...
A design which has a layout defined with CSS, instead of incorrectly utilized tables.